# Determinant of special diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A is a square matrix of any order whose diagonal entries are integers which are pairwise prime and all other entries are 1. Is there any method to find determinant of this matrix A.

Comment: Dietrich Burde, thanks. But here the diagonal entries are not equal,they are pairwise relatively prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $N$ and $\gamma_0,\dots,\gamma_N$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials in the diagonal entries. Then
$$
  \det A = \sum_{n=0}^{N-2}(-1)^{N-n-1}\left(N-n-1\right)\gamma_n + \gamma_N
$$
That the diagonal entries are integers or even pairwise prime is irrelevant.